# Show package description along with package name?

Tags: package

If i run `M-x package-list-packages`, it will list all packages with description like this.

[image]

If i run `M-x package-install`, it shows only package names like this.

[image]

How can i get package description along with package name?

Comment: You can 1) search package name within Package Menu; 2) if you have `helm`, try `M-x helm-list-elisp-packages`; 3) Write your own `package-install`-like command, learn `package-install` to find all possible package names, learn `describe-package` or others to find how to get package's description (summary), then use `package-install` to install package. You can use helm to write the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `helm` installed, you can use this function.

```lisp
(defun my-package-install-init ()
 (let ((packages (append (mapcar 'car package-alist)
                         (mapcar 'car package-archive-contents)
                         (mapcar 'car package--builtins))))
   (mapcar (lambda (pkg)
             (let* ((desc (or
                           (if (package-desc-p pkg) pkg)
                           (cadr (assq pkg package-alist))
                           (let ((built-in (assq pkg package--builtins)))
                             (if built-in
                                 (package--from-builtin built-in)
                               (cadr (assq pkg package-archive-contents))))))
                    (summary (if desc (package-desc-summary desc) "")))
               (cons (format "%-24s %s" pkg summary) (symbol-name pkg))))
           packages)))

(defun my-package-install ()
 (interactive)
 (package-install
  (helm
   :sources
   (helm-build-sync-source "Install Package"
     :candidates #'my-package-install-init
     :candidate-number-limit 9999
      :coerce #'intern))))
```

Here is a screen shot of it.

[image]

Comment: `helm-list-elisp-packages` also does the job, but it is not showing all packages.

Comment: I don't think so, `helm-list-elisp-packages` just uses the result of `package-list-package`, unless your `package-list-packages` can't show all packages.

Comment: for `packge-list-packages` i am getting more than 20 packages which start with `helm-*`, but for `helm-list-elisp-packages`, i am getting only 5 packages https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/4463796/9823100/de163276-58e1-11e5-9215-d124d07df839.png

Comment: @ChillarAnand Same thing here. I can't find the documentation, but looking at the sources, it appears that if there are updateable packages in your system, `helm-list-elisp-packages` automatically switches to `update` mode on startup (meaning it only shows you packages which you can update). Try pressing `M-A` to switch to the unfiltered list.

Comment: @ChillarAnand It is desired behavior and also documented, use `C-h m` to read its doc.  I didn't know this new behavior before.

Comment: @Francesco you can post that as an answer

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments by @xuchunyang, you can try `helm-list-elisp-packages`.

Please note that you might at first be confused: if your system is not fully up-to-date, `helm-list-elisp-packages` will open with a filtered view showing only upgradeable packages (and this bypasses the documented behaviour that the initial filter is determined by `helm-el-package-initial-filter`).

You can press <kbd>M-A</kbd> to switch to the unfiltered view. (And, as always, press <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> to see the mode help explaining other key bindings).